# Adding video with paperclip av-transcoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ffmpeg, paperclip

Okay so I tried this awhile back and I couldn't get it to work. So I started new and still struggling with this. I am able to upload images no problem. But for some reason I am getting errors when I try to upload videos. I have ffmpeg installed and the latest paperclip av-transcoder installed as well.

This is the error that I'm getting
[image]

This is my post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_attached_file :video, styles: {
    :medium => {
      :geometry => "640x480",
      :format => 'mp4'
    },
    :thumb => { :geometry => "160x120", :format => 'jpeg', :time => 10}
}, :processors => [:transcoder]
 validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
end
```

This is my post controller

```
def index
@posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def show
end

def new
@post = current_user.posts.build
end

def edit
end

def create
@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
if @post.save
  redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
else
  render :new
end
end

def update
if @post.update(post_params)
  redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.'
else
  render :edit
end
end

def destroy
@post.destroy
redirect_to posts_url
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_post
  @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
end

def correct_user
  @post = current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to posts_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this post" if     @post.nil?
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:description, :image, :video)
end

def bscenes_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:video)
end
end
```

This is the tag I am using on my show page

```
<%= video_tag bscene.video.url(:medium), controls: true, style: "max-width: 100%;" %>
```

I followed step by step the steps on this site
http://alloffices.io/posts/heroku-s3-paperclip-av-transcoder-for-video-uploads

Don't know why Im getting the NamError. Any help at all would be a ton of help

When I take away the "bscene" from the tag and controller I then get this when I upload.

[image]

Comment: Where is `bscene` supposed to be defined?

Comment: I believe in the post model but I have no clue. I just did what the steps told me to do. Now I tried to take away "bscene" from the tag and the controller and I got the video player to pop up but I got an error on the player